# filtering in a text file using awk

Tags: awk

i have a tab separated text file like this small example:

```
chr1    100499714   100499715   1
chr1    100502177   100502178   10
chr1    100502181   100502182   2
chr1    100502191   100502192   18
chr1    100502203   100502204   45
```

in the new file that I will make:

1- I want to select the rows based on the `4th` column meaning in the value of `4th` column is at least 10, I will keep the entire row otherwise will be filtered out.

2- in the next step the 4th column will be removed.
    the result will look like this:

```
chr1    100502177   100502178
chr1    100502191   100502192
chr1    100502203   100502204
```

to get such results I have tried the following code in `awk`:

```
cat input.txt | awk '{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3}' > out.txt
```

but I do not know how to implement the filtering step. do you know how to fix the code?

Answer (score 2):

Just put the condition before output:

```
cat input.txt | awk '$4 >= 10 {print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3}' > out.txt
```

Comment: 2 small kmprovements: don't need `cat` and use `OFS`: `awk '$4 >= 10 {print $1, $2, $3}' OFS='\t' input.txt > out.txt`

Answer (score 0):

here is another, might work better if you have many more fields

```
$ awk '$NF>=10{sub(/\t\w+$/,""); print}' file
```

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-only for `\w` or change the re to `/\t[^\t]+$/` or similar.